# Symfony - Add a column to a table without losing already generated classes

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

How can I add a column to a Database table without overwriting the classes already generated? (Doctrine) What files do I have to edit?

If I simply add the column in the database, I can't use the set and get functions of Doctrine ORM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use doctrine migrations. It allows you to modify your schema, update the database and your model without also losing the existing data in your database (in case it is relevant).

http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations

Applicable for symfony 1.4 too

Answer (score 4):

You should never edit the base classes (BaseFoo.class.php) as these get overwritten everytime you generate the models from the schema. The other files are never overwritten so it's safe to edit.

Answer (score 2):

### Doctrine 1.2:

Go to models folder, open **generated** class that reflects table to which you have added a column. Add

```
$this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 8, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'autoincrement' => true,
         'primary' => true,
         'length' => '8',
         ));
```

to `setTableDefinition` method.

**Note, that your changes will be overwritten on `generate-models`, so make sure you populate it to YAML/DB schema**

See [Doctrine Models Definition Manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#defining-models) for reference.

### Doctrine 2

Samples given for `Annotations Driver`, see [Doctrine2 manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/) for other [XML](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/xml-mapping.html) and [YAML](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/yaml-mapping.html) drivers
Just add new property to your `@Entity` class with `@Column` annotation on it:

```
/** @Column(type="integer", name="new_column") */
protected $new_column;
```