# Create a new table over an existing symfony instance

Tags: php, database, symfony1, model, symfony-1.4

as the title suggests, I'm struggling to understand how to create a new table and models and stuff in symfony without destroying everything and losing my data.

I'm running on symfony 1.4 Propel based.

what I'm trying to aim is to create a new table in an existing database via symfony.
But if I edit the schema file and then launch

```
 php symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

I'm gonna lose all the data. :-0

How can I impact changes in the schema over an already existing database?

thank u so much in advance

cheerz

-k-

Comment: If you're goin' to be putting the data back into the table then it would be wiser to use ALTER TABLE to update the contents.

Comment: no m8, what I gotta do is create a new table in an existing  database via symfony, if I edit the schema file and then launch php symfony doctrine:build-schema I'm gonna lose all the data. :-0

Comment: have you tried this? http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/2046/#msg_2046

Comment: yep I got in that post a few hrs ago :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146747/symfony-add-a-column-to-a-table-without-losing-already-generated-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SF 1.x does not have built in migration support. People have used doctrine migrations independently, but I am not aware of a good solution for propel.

The easiest solution I have seen is to export/backup the data in your current database, run the build-schema command to build the new version, and then import the data back. Its not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: but in this way I'm gonna loose all the data in my models, I need to find out a way to make the diffing of the model directory

Comment: if you backup and then restore the data, you will not lose it.

Comment: The only other alternative is to do the database changes yourself. This is easy if your are just adding a new field, or a discrete table.

Comment: as deep as I dig, as more I am considering that last option :)

Comment: ok, in the end I figured it out by doing all by hand. thnx a ton for the hint. what a nightmare! how can u not think about not implementing the migration feature in an ORM?! jeez man! I look to understand if an upgrade from 1.4 to 2.0 is possible

Comment: Well, your problem is propel. Most people have favored doctrine for a few years now, and in SF 1.4 they added support for doctrine migrations. I couldn't find any info on propel migrations. Symfony 2 is great (I'm using it now), but I don't think moving from propel would be easy.